# "systemctl start fstrim.timer" for ssd optimization not working on Debian 10

Tags: debian, ssd, systemctl, trim, fstrim

i just installed a 1TB kingston SSD, i cloned my HDD (with Debian 10) so nothing changed besides the performance, i want to set up TRIM for this SSD.

So i've done this:

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep -i TRIM
           *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)

$ sudo systemctl cat fstrim.service
# /lib/systemd/system/fstrim.service
[Unit]
Description=Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab
Documentation=man:fstrim(8)

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/fstrim -Av

$ sudo systemctl status fstrim.timer
● fstrim.timer - Discard unused blocks once a week
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
  Trigger: n/a
     Docs: man:fstrim
```

As you can see in the output from the third command fstrim.timer is inactive, so to activate it i think i should do this:

`$ sudo systemctl enable fstrim.service`

which outputs:

```
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
 
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.
```

and

`$ sudo systemctl start fstrim.timer`

which outputs:

`Failed to start fstrim.timer: Unit -.mount is masked.`

So i don't know what is happening there, i've already searched how to fix this but i can't find a proper answer, i hope someone can help me here, thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you enable the timer after unmasking it? `sudo systemctl unmask fstrim.timer`

Comment: It worked, i'm such a noob i did'n knew there was a unmask option, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As [ajgringo619](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/363044/ajgringo619) sugested i did: `sudo systemctl unmask fstrim.timer`

And then started fstrim.timer and cheked the status and everything was ok.

Comment: You mostly do not need to Trim on Linux. Also, this can even cause issues since manufacturers don't properly tell the features one SSD can have to the OS.

Comment: @X.LINK do you have a source for your claims?