# fstrim doesn't appear to have any timers, how do I make sure it works?

Tags: arch-linux, fstrim

"The util-linux package provides fstrim.service and fstrim.timer systemd unit files. Enabling the timer will activate the service weekly. The service executes fstrim(8) on all mounted filesystems on devices that support the discard operation."

From: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive

I wanted to make sure it runs weekly, as I've read it shouldn't run too often, and not too rarely.

However, it doesn't appear to have any timers:

```
# systemctl list-timers |grep fstrim
# cat /etc/systemd/system/fstrim.timer
cat: /etc/systemd/system/fstrim.timer: No such file or directory
```

The fstrim.service file itself is:

```
# systemctl cat fstrim.service
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.service
[Unit]
Description=Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab
Documentation=man:fstrim(8)
ConditionVirtualization=!container

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fstrim --listed-in /etc/fstab:/proc/self/mountinfo --verbose --quiet-unsupported
PrivateDevices=no
PrivateNetwork=yes
PrivateUsers=no
ProtectKernelTunables=yes
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectControlGroups=yes
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes
SystemCallFilter=@default @file-system @basic-io @system-service
```

Where is the weekly basis specified? How do I make sure it runs weekly, or at all?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/615337 i.e. you have to unmask+enable+start the timer not the service

Comment: have you check timer definition using `systemctl status fstrim.timer`  ? This should gave you where `fstrim.timer` is defined (in my case that was `/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.timer`).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files '*trim*'
UNIT FILE      STATE   VENDOR PRESET
fstrim.service static  -            
fstrim.timer   enabled enabled      

$ systemctl status fstrim.timer
● fstrim.timer - Discard unused blocks once a week
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.timer

$ grep Cal /lib/systemd/system/fstrim.timer
OnCalendar=weekly
```

Note that default systemd files live in `/lib/systemd/system` (and several other places) and locally customized ones live in `/etc/systemd/system`.